# Проблема с react-native navigation

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, expo

Проблема с react navigation, приложение галереи, нажимаешь на фото в общем списке и попадаешь на эту страницу где передается id фото с там делается запрос. Ниже фото логов. Если вставляю в Image data.urls.regular. Loading стает false до того так прилетают данные и выбрасывается ошибка так как data еще пуста, Как это дело исправить??

```
function ImageScreen({route}) {
  console.log('__INIT__')
  const {photoId} = route.params

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadImage(photoId))
    setLoading(false)
  }, [])

  const data = useSelector(state => state.image.image)

  console.log('loading', loading)
  console.log('data', data)

  const DownloadHandler = () => {
    alert('Save image... Joke')
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {loading ? <Loader/> :

        <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={.7} onPress={DownloadHandler}>
          <Image style={styles.image} source={{uri: data}}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      }
    </View>
  );
}

export default ImageScreen
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что за функция ‘loadImage’?

Comment: Запрос к серверу фото по id

Comment: Если он асинхронный, то в нём и проблема